# Jenkins Pipeline Stash not Stashing file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, declarative

I am trying to use Jenkins `stash`/`unstash` for the first time, and I am unable to successfully stash my files.

This is the path to the file:

```
/opt/cicd/jenkins/workspace/DEVOPS/stageParams.yaml
```

This is my stash command:

```
{stash name: "config", includes: "/DEVOPS/stageParams.yaml"}
```

I keep receiving this error:

```
ERROR:No files included in stash 'config'
```

Please help!

Comment: the path should be `DEVOPS/stageParams.yaml`

Comment: @uncletall is right. In a unix like system the "/" refers to the root directory (where /opt is located). When you are using the path like this /DEVOPS/... your telling jenkins to look for the DEVOPS folder at the root level. When you are already in the workspace (what I asume) you can use it like DEVOPS/stageParams.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/opt/cicd/jenkins/workspace/DEVOPS/stageParams.yaml`
`/DEVOPS/stageParams.yaml`
Two path above are different. 
Let try:
`{stash name: "config", includes: "DEVOPS/stageParams.yaml"}`